# COUNT(*) returning number of rows before GROUP BY clause?

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have the follwing query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM mydb.table1 t1
JOIN mydb.table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
WHERE t1.user_id = 44 AND t1.date_deleted IS NULL
GROUP BY t2.system_id, CASE WHEN t2.system_id IS NULL THEN t2.id ELSE 0 END
```

It returns `COUNT(*)` = `6`, when it should be returning `1` since all six rows for this user have the same `t2.system_id` (so they should be grouped).

If I change the query to select `*` instead of `COUNT(*)`, it only returns a single row. If I then remove the `GROUP BY` clause, six rows are returned.

This makes me think `COUNT(*)` is returning the row count before the `GROUP BY` clause is executed, but from what I've read that's not how it's supposed to work.

Is this behavior normal?

Comment: Have you tried moving the CASE inside the COUNT()?

Comment: @lokulin the CASE is part of the GROUP BY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select count(*) from (
  SELECT *
    FROM mydb.table1 t1
    JOIN mydb.table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
    WHERE t1.user_id = 44 
      AND t1.date_deleted IS NULL
    GROUP BY t2.system_id, 
      CASE WHEN t2.system_id IS NULL THEN t2.id ELSE 0 END
) q1
```

`count` gives you the number of (not null) items in each group, so yes, it is definitely working the way it is intended. This means that if you just want the total number of groups, the easiest way is to just wrap it in another query.

Answer (score 1):

It returns the count of items in each group. You have one group with six items in it, so it returns one row containing a column valued 6.

Comment: So how would I get the number of groups, instead of the number of items inside each group, then?